# Sigma.js border on all nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-visualization, graph-visualization, sigma.js

I'm implementing a visualization with [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) (using the [neighborhood plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods), if that's of any relevance). Out of the box, Sigma.js displays a rectangular label and blurred border on all *hovered* nodes. For greater visual clarity, I'm interested in implementing a border (preferably not blurred) strictly around the circular node on *all* nodes as a default, rather than just hovered or clicked ones. I understand the prepackaged settings allow alterations only to hovered node borders. Any guidance regarding modifying all node borders is greatly appreciated. I anticipate this will involve tinkering with the original Sigma.js source, but it is unclear where. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this resource which answers this question, and also explains why Sigma.JS relies on custom renderers to modify node attributes such as border.

[On the topic of Sigma custom renderers](http://yomguithereal.github.io/articles/node-border-renderer/)

Hope this helps others out there with similar questions!